# Testing for cross-site scripting (XSS) vulnerabilities in continuous integration environment

Tags: security, testing, continuous-integration, xss

Our company is fairly new to continuous integration (CI), using [Codeship](https://codeship.com/) to help with automated tasks. We have traditionally tested for XSS vulnerabilities manually using the [XSS Me Firefox Add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/xss-me/). Because we produce and maintain a large number of sites each year, we'd love to automate this XSS testing during our deployments. However, I haven't been able to find such a tool.

Is there an XSS testing tool that plays nicely with CI? We're not married to Codeship. If there's a more suitable CI service out there, we would have no problem jumping ship. Pun intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of Codeship as a operating system, where you can run some aplications. I use Wapiti for security testing. 
You can run the Wapiti and then deploy the report to a other server.

Running the Wapiti.

```
wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/wapiti/wapiti/wapiti-2.2.1/wapiti-2.2.1.zip
unzip wapiti-2.2.1.zip
cd wapiti-2.2.1/src/
chmod -x wapiti-2.2.1/bin/wapit
python wapiti.py http://www.exemple.com/ -o report
```

[image]

More information, see in: http://wapiti.sourceforge.net/